# Serializar XML e salvar no Oracle com C# e ADO

Tags: c#, xml, oracle, ado.net, xpath

Gostaria de saber se existe algo equivalente em Oracle pra este `select` em SQL Server:

```
select NickName, ExternalId1 from Basics where externalId1 = @externalId1 for xml auto, elements;
```

E para este `select` abaixo:

```
select
x.n.value('OperationId[1]', 'int'),
x.n.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
x.n.value('MaxTime[1]', 'float')
from @xml.nodes('/*[1]') x(n);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para o primeiro, sim. Fica igual, na verdade.

```
select NickName, ExternalId1 
from Basics 
where externalId1 = @externalId1 
for xml auto, elements;
```

Quanto ao segundo, o SQL Server aceita `XPath`, mas acredito que para funcionar, `@xml` precisa estar populado com uma consulta antes.

Comment: vamos ver se entendi  este select NickName, ExternalId1 from Basics where externalId1 = @externalId1 for xml auto, elements; em SqlServer é o mesmo para Oracle? Obrigado.

Comment: @eddiedev Exatamente.

Comment: Interessante. Achei que mudava a forma de envio desse xml para um banco Oracle. Obrigado

Comment: @eddiedev Se a resposta do Cigano resolveu seu problema, marque ela como aceita, para que todos possam saber como você resolveu seu problema.